# Call jquery function on click of a bootstrap pagination link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I want to call jquery function on click of a bootstrap pagination link.

Supppose I want to traverse from page 1 to 2, a jquery function should be called.

I am using following code but it is not working:

```
 $("ul.pagination").on("click","li", function(){
     alert("page changed");
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

use `ul.pagination li a` for event like this http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/fdfaLrnz/

```
$('ul.pagination li a').on('click',function(e){
    /* your code*/
});
```