# Call jquery function on Bootstrap pagination

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm trying to write code for a calendar where the user can switch between weeks.

This is my html:

```
<nav id="weekSwitcher" align="center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li id="previous">
            <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">xyz</a></li>
        <li id="next">
            <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And this is my jquery:

```
$('#previous').on('click', function() {
    // More code...
});

$('#next').on('click', function() {
    // More code...
});
```

I already saw this Question : [Call jquery...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952670/call-jquery-function-on-click-of-a-bootstrap-pagination-link)

But this didn't really help me since I want to decide which 'button' is clicked.

How can call my functions when a user clicks to switch between the weeks?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are selecting `$('#previous')`. There is at most one element with an id with value "previous". That means you already know which button is pressed when the corresponding click handler is executed. What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: @Sumurai8 My problem is that now nothing happens if a user clicks on the arrows to switch between the weeks.

Comment: Well. Start with adding `console.log( "[Click handler <name> is clicked]" );` to your click handlers. Open your developer console, reload the page, and click the arrows. Does it log anything? If yes, then the problem is with the logic in your handlers. If no, you might need to bind to the underlying "a" element, or you might be binding to an element that does not yet exist in case this dynamically loads. In that case use delegation.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Ok, thank you for the quick help! It didn't log anything so now I'll try your suggestions for this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you don't wrap your code inside a $(document).ready block:

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#previous').on('click', function() {
        alert("Previous alert");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#next').on('click', function() {
        alert("Next alert");
    });
});
```

or cleaner:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#previous').on('click', function() {
        alert("Previous alert");
    });

    $('#next').on('click', function() {
        alert("Next alert");
    });
});
```

Personally I would also use a second id for the your links (a tag), for example previous-link and next-link. The reason is, that the click() event is focused on the link itself (a tag) and not on the pagination list elements (li element in the ul list) - but that's just my personal opinion. Additionally you can also use the shorter notation for events:

```
<nav id="weekSwitcher" align="center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li id="previous">
            <a href="#" id="previous-link" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="next">
            <a href="#" id="next-link" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the jQuery block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#previous-link').click(function() {
        alert("Previous alert");
    });

    $('#next-link').click(function() {
        alert("Next alert");
    });
});
```